# To what temperature should you take candied citrus peels?

Tags: candy

I have been examining scores of recipes for candied citrus peels and I am unable to find an answer to this question. Most recipes indicate pretty standard candy making instructions; heat sugar/water solution to 230, add orange peels, cook for some amount of time or reduce by some amount.

But that's the part that I'm having a hard time with. Time makes a big difference with candy making. Wouldn't leaving them cook for, say, an hour, produce drastically different results than 30 minutes? Why does there seem to be no recipe out there that uses actual candy making terms for this recipe?

I just need some idea of what temperature to take the sugar solution up to. I'm going to guess firm or hard ball?

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding your questions. From the "scores of recipes" surely you have found one simple one like this: Prep:15min Cook: 45min Ready in:1hr Place peel strips in large saucepan and cover with water. Bring to a boil over high heat, then reduce heat and simmer 10 minutes longer. Drain. Repeat this process two more times. In a medium saucepan, heat sugar and water over high heat until boiling. Place peel in sugar mixture, reduce heat and simmer 15 minutes, until sugar is dissolved. Remove peel with slotted spoon and dry on wire rack overnight. Store in airtight container.

Comment: @piglet your example recipe only contains cooking times. This will result in highly variable end temperature/sugar concentration, and no way to get consistently good results in different setups. Matthew is asking about the temperature, which is a good indicator of being done, instead of cooking time, which is a very bad indicator.

Comment: @rumtscho I am getting sick of your petty pedantic editing. Please stop victimising me. Sie gehen mir auf die Nerven.

Comment: @piglet Sorry that my comments annoy you. There are two cases in which I cannot stop interacting with your posts. First, there are guidelines for posts here, and my job as a moderator is to remove content which does not fit the rules. I think this is rare in your case now that you have spent some time on the site, but sometimes even the most experienced users forget the exact rules. Second, if you post something which I am convinced to contain misleading facts and therefore mislead other people, I will still point out this, so the others know that the opinion expressed in your (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) post is controversial. In both cases, it is part of the Stack Exchange rules that the interest of the thousands of page visitors have a higher priority than the interest of the poster to not feel annoyed. Yes, this leads to pedantic behaviour; this is expected and desired, as in this respect, it is more similar to an academic peer review than to a pleasant conversation between friends. In all other cases (like the one here, for example), I will stop posting comments addressed to you, or interfering with your posts. I am still available for discussions if you start and ask me to join.

Comment: @rumtscho Danke. Now let me be pedantic. In your correction of my post you claim my example only contains cooking times and that it is a bad indicator. That is your opinion, which according to the rules is not to be given. If you read the text properly, you would have seen it was boiling in water only. Since when has time been an irrelevance in cooking? Or causes inconsistency? Cookery remains an art, as much as you would like it to be pure science, and should be treated as such. I share my experience, not scientific fact and fiction and certainly not opinion dressed as science.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you are looking for a specific temp (i.e.; crack or soft ball stage) after adding the citrus since you have already "contaminated" the syrup.  My preferred recipe is from Epicurious.com (http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/Candied-Citrus-Peel-107434).  I have used it twice with great results and am going to be making again very soon for the holidays.

Comment: Great answer. I had been wondering why this candy suddenly seemed so flexible in making, while sugar is normally tricky at best. Now it clicked -> Of course, all that natural citrus peel would not obey strict sugar laws and be highly variable!